# How to remove a line from string?

Tags: java, string, input, character, line

I am updating new lines to my string like:

> mystring=mystring+"some input string"+"\n";

but when I need to delete last line from the string, what should I do?

Comment: Post the sample code.

Comment: As a small improvement on your current code you could probably use "+=" operator

myString+="Some input string\n";

Answer (score 1):

Simply try with [String#trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

```
String  result= string.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
mystring = mystring.substring(0, 
                    mystring.lastIndexOf('\n', mystring.size()-1)+1);
```

This assumes you don't have `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all `'\n'` from the `String`, you can use:

```
mystring =  mystring.remove('\n','');
```